# Websocket server and Mobile clients

Tags: javascript, android, ios, websocket

I have a Tomcat based server which serves as a Websocket end point (used javax.websocket)  for my web based JS app. I am serving out json based data (queried from my database) via the web sockets. I am not using websockets to serve out HTML/JS pages.

Now we are building a native mobile app of our JS web app. There doesnt seem to be good native support for Websockets on Android and ios.

I would like to keep the server code base common to both JS client and the mobile client.

What would be your suggestion for such a situation? Write a different server for mobile clients?

I found this http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps. They suggest SocketRocket for ios and https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket for Android.

I have never heard of these people / companies. Not sure of their antecedents and if their apps are bug free.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but I tried this once, and decided to use a webpage that uses the websocket. Each app will display a webview accessing the page. All recent iOS SDK versions support this, but only the newer (4.4+) Androids will.

If you do not want to use webviews, I recommend [Tavendo Autobahn](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid) for Android. I had a problem that my server's websocket would disconnect all the time. I had to implement a reconnection routine every couple of seconds on the app.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Luke. One point I forgot to mention in my question is that I am not using websockets to server out pages but rather to serve out data from my database in the form of json objects. In any case I will take a look at Travendo Autobahn. Was your disconnects due to cellular network issues or some thing to do with your code or Autobahn code?

Comment: The problem was the server. For some reason, our server would shut down connections. We could see this happening on both Android and iOS apps

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library on android for websockets https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets

Works good with Spring WebSockets.

Sorry for messy answer, I'm in hurry, write in comments if u have questions